# How to make text as a sprite in turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

For example I want to do something like this:

```
textSprite=new object(text("Hello"))
turtle.display(textSprite)
```

**-Then do**

```
time.sleep(10)
textSprite.hide()
```

**-Or**

```
while i<100:
    time.sleep(10)
    textsprite.size=i
```

**-Or**

```
textSprite.x=10
textSprite.y=100
time.sleep(100)
textSprite.x=20
textSprite.y=200
```

I tried searching google but I got no answers.

---

update: some question changes have been made

Answer (score 1):

Since Python is generally object-oriented, and turtle specifically is, you can create your own `TextSprite` class using turtle as underpinning:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class TextSprite(Turtle):
    DEFUALT_FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'normal')

    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(visible=False)

        self.text = text
        self.font = self.DEFUALT_FONT

        self.penup()

    def setfont(self, font):
        self.font = font

    def showtext(self):
        self.write(self.text, align='center', font=self.font)

    def hidetext(self):
        self.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from turtle import Screen

    screen = Screen()

    sprite = TextSprite("Hello")

    sprite.goto(100, 100)
    sprite.color('blue')
    sprite.setfont(('Times Roman', 24, 'bold'))

    sprite.showtext()

    screen.ontimer(sprite.hidetext, 10_000)  # ten seconds

    screen.exitonclick()
```